# Why is SynchronizationContext.Current null in my Winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

I just wrote this code:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(
    state => DoUpdateInUIThread((Abc)state), 
    abc);
```

but System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current is null

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [this explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaelr/synchronizationcallback).

> SynchronizationContext.Current is only set in the main thread (which is the only thread where you don't actually need it)

The blog post proposes a workaround.

Answer (score 20):

To get it to work.

In your class

```
private SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;
```

In the **UI thread** (main thread)

```
synchronizationContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

In the worker thread

```
synchronizationContext.Post(    
   state => DoUpdateInUIThread((Abc)state),     
   abc);
```

Comment: How is the syncronizationContext instantiated in, or passed to, the worker thread?

Comment: Let's say you're using a `BackgroundWorker` in your form. If you save off `SynchronizationContext.Current` in your constructor or load event as a class level variable, it'll be accessible in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler. Alternatively, if you're doing the work in another class, like a presenter, you could create the presenter on the UI thread and save off the context in the constructor.