# Cross threading problem: Invalid operationexception was handeled

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I am making a program that import emails from txt files and send a message to them , but i am facing a problem , currently i am using a thread for the sending mail method to prevent the program to stop responding , the exact problem title is:

```
Invalid operationexception was handeled
>>> Cross-thread operation not valid:
    Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

here is the code

```
    int success = 0;
    int failed = 0;
    int total = 0;
    bool IsRunning;

List<string> list = new List<string>();

private void addmails()
    {
        string path = textBox2.Text;

        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            list.Add(line);
        }
        IsRunning = true;
    }
    private void sendmails(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsRunning == true)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked != true)
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(comboBox1.Text);
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text);
                message.Subject = textBox4.Text;
                //message.Body = richTextBox1.Text;
                if (textBox5.Text != "")
                {
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox5.Text));
                }

                foreach (string eachmail in list)
                {
                    if (IsRunning == true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            message.To.Add(eachmail);
                            client.Send(message);
                            listBox1.Items.Add("Successfully sent the message to  : " + eachmail);
                            success++;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add("Failed to send the message to  : " + eachmail);
                            failed++;
                        }
                        message.To.Clear();

                        total++;

                        Thread.Sleep(15);

                        label18.Text = total.ToString();
                        label19.Text = success.ToString();
                        label21.Text = failed.ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                IsRunning = false;
                button3.Text = "Send";
            }

        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button3.Text == "Send")
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
            button3.Text = "Stop";

            addmails();

           // IsRunning = true;

            Thread t2 = new Thread(sendmails); // when using that thread i get a cross threading error
            t2.Start();

        }
        else
        {
            IsRunning = false;
            button3.Text = "Send";
            MessageBox.Show("Sending Mails Operation has been terminated","Abort",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Comment: Please try to avoid having the problem-description occur only in the title. You should post the actual exception and where it occurs as well.

Comment: As @Lasse V. Karlsen said, what is the *actual* exception you see?

Comment: the exact problem title is : Invalid operationexception was handeled >>> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using accessing UI members from a different thread rather than the thread that they are created on, you have to use `Control.Invoke` whenever you want to access `control` members or method from another thread.
So, to get this to work you have to "I really would not do this but just answering your question":

```
if (IsRunning == true)
{
    bool checkbox1Checked;
    string textBox6Text;
    string textBox7Text;
    string textBox3Text;
    string textBox1Text;
    string textBox4Text;
    string richTextBox1Text;
    string textBox5Text;

    MethodInvoker getValues = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
        checkbox1Checked = checkbox1.Checked;
        textBox6Text = textBox6.Text;
        textBox7Text = textBox7.Text;
        textBox3Text = textBox3.Text;
        textBox1Text = textBox1.Text;
        textBox4Text = textBox4.Text;
        richTextBox1Text = richTextBox1.Text;
        textBox5Text = textBox5.Text;
    });

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(getValues);
    }
    else
    {
        getValues();
    }

    if (checkBox1Checked != true)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(comboBox1Text);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox6Text, textBox7Text);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(textBox3Text, textBox1Text);
        message.Subject = textBox4Text;
        //message.Body = richTextBox1Text;
        if (textBox5Text != "")
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox5Text));
        }

        foreach (string eachmail in list)
        {
            if (IsRunning == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    message.To.Add(eachmail);
                    client.Send(message);

                    MethodInvoker addToListBox = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Successfully sent the message to  : " + eachmail);
                    }); 
                    if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        listBox1.Invoke(addToListBox);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        addToListBox();
                    }

                    success++;
                }
                catch
                {
                    MethodInvoker addToListBox = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Failed to send the message to  : " + eachmail);
                    });

                    if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        listBox1.Invoke(addToListBox);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        addToListBox();
                    }

                    failed++;
                }
                message.To.Clear();

                total++;

                Thread.Sleep(15);

                MethodInvoker updateSatatus = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    label18.Text = total.ToString();
                    label19.Text = success.ToString();
                    label21.Text = failed.ToString();
                });

                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(updateSatatus);
                }
                else
                {
                    updateSatatus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        IsRunning = false;
        if (button3.InvokeRequired)
        {
            button3.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { button3.Text = "Send"; } ));
        }
        else
        {
            button3.Text = "Send";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: man very big thanks to you , you really cleared a lot of things to me

Answer (score 5):

**The problem is that UI (WinForms) controls are being accessed from a non-UI thread (the newly spawned one).**

Don't do that. Either `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke` or `SynchronizationContext.Post/Send` can be used, depending upon exactly what is required. Looking up this issue using the keywords above will lead to many examples.

Another alternative is to use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) object and a the `RunWorkCompleted`/`ProgressChanged` events and *pass in* all the required information before sending anything. (E.g. don't "read" the UI in the new thread.)

Happy coding.

---

Resources / additional reading:

[How do I change a ComboBox data from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556330/threading-cross-threading-in-c-net-how-do-i-change-combobox-data-from-another) - Small example of Invoke/BeginInvoke including a nice little wrapper for it. All that is "needed" to solve the problem in the post.

[What's up with BeginInvoke?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/begininvoke.aspx) - Discusses restrictions with WinForms control access, how windows messaging works, and the use of Invoke/BeginInvoke. A very good read.

[Understand SynchronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizationContext.aspx?msg=2888338) - Similar to the previous, but focuses on using SC and not Invoke/BeginInvoke. Only read after previous link.

[BackgroundWorker and SynchronizationContext](http://msmvps.com/blogs/manoj/archive/2005/11/03/74120.aspx) - I prefer to use SynchronicationContext over Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke (I like the interface better and there is no need to check `InvokedRequired` or similar). This discusses SC in context of a BGW. Being from 2005, it uses the old "delegate" syntax. If using SC, make sure to use the SC *obtained from the UI thread*. See [Why is SynchronizationContext.Current null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709552/why-is-synchronizationcontext-current-null-in-my-winforms-application) In my applications I often have static `Send/Post` wrapper methods that take care of all the details.

Comment: i`d be thankful if you provided some code for explanation . and thanks a lot for clearing things up

Comment: @BOSS I have updated my post with some (relatively good) articles.