# SynchronizationContext.Current is null on Main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms, synchronizationcontext

`SynchronizationContext.Current` is null on Main thread and I have had a hard time figuring this one out.

```
static class Program
{
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ctx = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
            // ctx is null here
        }
}
```

I am running on .NET 4.6.1. It is a mixed Winforms and WPF app. The entry point is WinForms. Here are some screenshots of such evidence:

[image]
[image]

It is also not related to posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953281/workaround-for-issue-in-net-4-0-where-synchronizationcontext-current-is-null) as I am using newer .NET version and seems mentioned issue was patched already. Any other good ideas?

Comment: Exactly where is SynchronizationContext.Current null? Please provide a repo of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709552/why-is-synchronizationcontext-current-null-in-my-winforms-application

Comment: @mm8 - Updated.  VladimirArustamian - this is not the case for me. I have mentioned that in the last paragraph in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is no `SynchronizationContext` available when the entry point (`Main`) of your application is hit. You need to wait for the framework to initialize it.

In a Windows Forms application this happens when the first form is created. So only after the `Application.Run` method has been called, the `SynchronizationContext.Current` property will actually return a synchronization context.

Comment: That is totally true. In my case there is no formal application as it is a multi-window workspace so I need to initialize my first form to force context creation.